# Diamonds break the badge baseline

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

<sup>^Woo alliteration.</sup>

On non-question linked badges (e.g. mortarboard, legendary, civic duty, suffrage etc.) moderators names appear below the baseline of the letters:

[image]

Perhaps more noticeable on the beta theme:

[image]

Comment: Chrome 18.0.1025.162

Comment: Always blame it on the mods, that's the way we like it.

Comment: Blame the diamond; it's a way too heavy to carry it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue in the current build of our sites. If the problem remains please let me know.