# Stack Exchange needs more designers? or a better way to track design bugs across the network

Tags: support, stack-exchange, design

There needs to be a way (*or I would much like there to be a way*) for a Stack Exchange employee to keep an active monitor on what happens in the [design] [bug] meta section for each site. In terms of the SE engine most issues tend to be network wide so once it is addressed on one site it is solved on all others. Sometimes bugs fall through and SE mods must nag, ping and email the SE Team to fix it (another issue altogether which I think was mentioned in another meta post)

Design bug issues on other hand can be different, all CSS files may or may not be the same.

Seeing that there is only one designer (that I am aware of) on the https://stackexchange.com/about/team is there a way for this designer to properly monitor issues that have been left unattended for long period of times (especially those that may not have the priority in the eyes of SE but still needs resolve) or maybe some vague idea/word from Stack Exchange Inc. increasing their design team.

Wouldn't be that great to be overworking the one guy too much

<sub>One of the scenarios: Posted a bug [Users listed on Badge slightly misaligned](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/users-listed-on-badge-slightly-misaligned), there was a [comment](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/users-listed-on-badge-slightly-misaligned#comment1120_822) saying it will be addressed, 15 months later https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E79F.png.</sub>

Comment: Just as a *side note*, your linked bug in the footnote is [network wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129266/diamonds-break-the-badge-baseline) and also an example of the [three column overlap bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken).

Comment: This [bug I reported](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/the-you-dont-have-full-edit-privileges-message-is-very-unnoticeable) has been open a while.

Comment: @Rory true, thanks for the links definitely the same bugs, should I escalate everything to meta.stackoverflow.com next time?

Comment: FWIW, he *can* monitor them all [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/3273/jin), not sure whether he can keep up with them all though ;)